# What is messing up my system clock?

Tags: 14.04, networking, cron, ntp

Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, 64-bit

I came in to work this morning and noticed that the clock on my system was off by approximately 3 minutes, as compared to the clock on my phone. That seems odd, since my system is on 24/7 and should be keeping the time synced with `ntp.ubuntu.com`, right? And I've never noticed this problem before.

In the system configuration, the "Time & Date" settings are set to  set the time automatically from the internet.

So I started digging...

First I used `ntpdate` to update the time. This worked, but a few minutes later the time was incorrect again - by approximate -217 seconds.

Next, I installed `ntpd`, hoping that continuous updating would solve the problem. I reset the date using `ntpdate` and started the `ntpd` service. No luck - a few minutes later, the time was off, again by approximately -217 seconds.

The offset of -217 seconds seems pretty consistent - ie. it doesn't appear to drift once it hits that difference. This suggest to me that there's something on my system resetting the time periodically, and because the change is too large, `ntpd` will not adjust it.

After some more experimenting, I have determined that whatever is resetting my clock is doing it approximately every 5 minutes. I've looking in my `crontab` and the `crontab` for root, as well as the system-wide cron files.

A couple of additional details:

1. I have joined by system to a Windows domain using Likewise Open.
2. There *was* a major change to our network over the weekend - we switched from one connection to a different (faster) connection. However, I appear to be the only one experiencing this issue (amongst about 30 Windows PCs, Ubuntu PCs, and Macs).

So, a couple of questions:

- What could be doing this?
- If a scheduled job is not in my `cron` files, where could it be?

Comment: You could try running it offline to see if it is the hardware clock - setting the time manually or with ntpdate, disabling the existing time update (using the thing in settings might work) and then having a cron run every so often to update it could work

Comment: I did wonder about the hardware clock, but it's odd that it always wants to jump ahead the same amount, at the same interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be leading to the solution that a domain member should not have more than 5 minutes clock skew. See http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/files/pbiso/Manuals/likewise-open-54-guide.html#id2944830 
I suggest the settings of Likewise make sure that this time difference cannot occur.
A windows domain member would normally sync with the PDC but it could be possible that your client syncs with an out-of-sync DC. Just a thought.

Comment: Looks like this was it. Checked our primary domain controller & discovered that the time service was not updating properly. It looks like it has not been updated in some time, and the time was slowly drifting farther & farther away from the "real" time. I *think* I've fixed it by updating the primary domain controller - I'm gonna have to check it in a little while & see if I can figure out if it's updating properly.